# How to check/fix image rotation before upload image using PHP

Tags: php

I have a issiue when uploading a image taken using iphone.
I am trying to use PHP and the imgrotate function to automaticly decide if the image needs to be rotated to the correct possition, before uploading it to the server.

**My html code:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
     <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                        Choose img<input type="file" name="file" id="imgInp">
                    </span>
                </span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

**The PHP code im using:**
Also return a error: Warning: imagerotate() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in.

Anyone have a working code for this scenario?

```
<?php

$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);


 if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
        switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
            case 3:
                $image = imagerotate($filename, -180, 0);
                break;
            case 6:
                $image = imagerotate($filename, 90, 0);
                break;
            case 8:
                $image = imagerotate($filename, -90, 0);
                break;
        } 
    }

    imagejpeg($image, $filename, 90);

?>
```

Comment: `imagerotate()` requires an `image resource` rather than a filename. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using `imagerotate` wrong. It expect first parameter to be resource while you are passing the filename. Check [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php)

Try this:

```
<?php

$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    $imageResource = imagecreatefromjpeg($filePath); // provided that the image is jpeg. Use relevant function otherwise
    switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 3:
        $image = imagerotate($imageResource, 180, 0);
        break;
        case 6:
        $image = imagerotate($imageResource, -90, 0);
        break;
        case 8:
        $image = imagerotate($imageResource, 90, 0);
        break;
        default:
        $image = $imageResource;
    } 
}

imagejpeg($image, $filename, 90);

?>
```

Do not forget to free the memory by adding following two lines:

```
imagedestroy($imageResource);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: I get: Notice: Undefined index: tmp_path , cant see this when dumping the FILES either.

Comment: Works, but it rotate the image one step to much. (iphone5)

Comment: @sdfgg45 in that case, you need to correct the logic of finding correct orientation and applying appropriate rotation. Can you try now? I just updated the code to apply rotation as mentioned in the PHP manual example.

Comment: That seam to be the correct one, but if the image dont need rotation the imagecreation fails, is there a default case if the image dont need to be turned and just created?

Comment: @sdfgg45 added a default case.