# how to fix Orientation of the image and upload image using PHP

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to upload an image and fix the rotate of the image, then update it to a server, I have to use the answer in this link: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287437/how-to-check-fix-image-rotation-before-upload-image-using-php#answer-34287543)
but it does not work still the image with the wrong orientation

the code in php:

```
    //START Update the user image
if(isset($_POST['user_image_id'])){

    $upload_image_id = $_POST['user_image_id'];
    $user_image = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
    $filePath = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];

   $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name']));
    $exif = exif_read_data($filePath);
    if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
        switch($exif['Orientation']) {
           case 8:
               $image = imagerotate($image,90,0);
               break;
           case 3:
               $image = imagerotate($image,180,0);
               break;
           case 6:
               $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
               break;
       }
   }
    // $image now contains a resource with the image oriented correctly

    //create image target to upload
    $image_target = $folder_target.basename($_FILES['user_image']['name']);

    //upload the image the and update the name of the image
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $image_target)){
        if ($conn->query("UPDATE `users` SET `image`='$user_image' WHERE `id` LIKE '$upload_image_id'")){
            echo 1;
        }else{
            echo "not update the name, Proplem";
        }
    }else{
        echo 'image not uploaded';
    }

}
```

I used the image library "https://github.com/Al-Alloush/JavaScript-Load-Image", to fix the orientation  of the image in browser  but when I submit and uploaded the image to server still the same oriented

[image: before uploading]
[image: image display like that after uploading to the server]

please Help, :)

Comment: Two things I would suggest: 1) Make your own filename, never use the original filename from the user's upload. 2) Save the manipulated image to your target, instead of moving the now-useless uploaded temp file.

Comment: i create a folder for every user uploading the image, under this folder all the user's image
loke that
$folder_target = "users_image/".$id."/";
$image_target = $folder_target.basename($_FILES['user_image']['name']);

Comment: Right, I usually make a new image name with a sequential ID, so that whatever that user had named their file on their computer, doesn't "taint" my server lol ;) So like: `$image_target = $folder_target .'image_'. $imgid . $extension;` Where I got extenion from type, and imgid from a pre-db entry or some other setup. ANYHOO... Samir's answer worked out for you!

Comment: any way thanks for you ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't saved your image after rotating it. Save is as below before uploading it.

```
imagejpeg($image, $filePath);

//upload the image the and update the name of the image
if(move_uploaded_file($filePath, $image_target)){
    ....
}
```

> Note: `imagejpeg` should be used for images with `JPG` extension. For `PNG`, use `imagepng`.