# PHP Fixing image orientation from mobile device before creating thumbnail & upload

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have aa form for a user to upload an image to a gallery, at the moment certain images taken by mobile phone & tablets are displaying with the wrong orientation.

I'm trying to read the EXIF data to correct this, then create a thumbnail.
I'm reading the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48467336/how-to-fix-orientation-of-the-image-and-upload-image-using-php) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287437/how-to-check-fix-image-rotation-before-upload-image-using-php#answer-34287543) but neither of these continue to adjust the image before saving it onto the server and I can't figure out if I have to save it somewhere before the thumbnail creation.

My script validation works correctly making sure the file is the correct format, doesn't exist and is smaller than 5mb.

I've set my variables as;

```
$userimage = $_FILES["userimage"]["name"];
$filePath = $_FILES['userimage']['tmp_name'];
$filetype = $_FILES["userimage"]["type"];
$targetDir = "../public/img/uploads/";
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $userimage;  
$targetThumbFilePath = "../public/img/uploads/thumbs/";
$ext = pathinfo(strtolower($userimage), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Then this is my code for creating thumbnail and uploading;
(Once I fix this problem I know that the filenames should be assigned by me).

```
$exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['userimage']['tmp_name']);
if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {

    $image = imagecreatefromstring($filePath); 
    switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 3:
        $image = imagerotate($image, 180, 0);

        break;
        case 6:
        $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);

        break;
        case 8:
        $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);

        break;
        default:                        
    } 
}

if (move_uploaded_file($image, $targetFilePath)){

  $upload = '../public/img/uploads/' . $_FILES["userimage"]["name"];
  list ($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize ($upload);

  //switches content-type and calls the imagecreatefrom... function
  if ($type == 1)
  {                    
      $image = imagecreatefromgif($upload);
  }
  elseif ($type == 2)
  {                    
      $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload);
  }
  elseif ($type == 3)
  {                    
      $image = imagecreatefrompng($upload);
  }

  $src = '../public/img/uploads/thumbs/thumb-' . $_FILES["userimage"]["name"];                 

  // calculate thumbnail size
  $new_width = 616;

  $new_height = floor( $height * ( $new_width / $width ) );

  // create a new temporary image
  $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

  // copy and resize old image into new image 
  imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );

  //switches content-type and saves thumbnail
  if ($type == 1)
  {
      imagegif($tmp_img, $src);
  }
  elseif ($type == 2)
  {
      imagejpeg($tmp_img, $src);
  }
  elseif ($type == 3)
  {
      imagepng($tmp_img, $src);
  }

}
```

Comment: `imagecreatefromstring` takes in image in the form of a string, not the file path.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` accepts file path as an argument not the image resource as returned by `imagerotate`

Comment: @Dharman So I need to store the `$image` created by `imagerotate` before moving it?

Comment: I recommend you to read in full the PHP docs regarding all of those functions first. PHP docs have great examples how to use the code. Some functions work on file path and others want a resource.

Comment: @Dharman I was trying to pass it to `move_uploaded_file` like that because the documentation for `imagerotate` only includes `JPG` files?

Comment: The GD library supports multiple image formats: JPG, PNG, GIF, BMP ...

Comment: @Dharman GD? excuse my ignorance.

Comment: [PHP GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) is PHP's standard library for image manipulation