# Image showing rotated anticlockwise in website

Tags: html, css, image, image-processing

Today I encountered a new issue. when I uploaded the image it shows rotated anticlockwise (-90deg). I thought it has issues with orientation so I tried adding this css `image-orientation: from-image;` but it doesn't worked.

HTML code:

```
<section class=" parallax-section content-parallax-section" data-scrollax-parent="true">
<div class="bg" data-bg="includes/images/bg/2.jpg" data-scrollax="properties: { translateY: '200px' }" style="background-image: url(&quot;includes/images/bg/2.jpg&quot;);"></div>
</section>
```

Related Css Classes

```
.bg {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-origin: content-box;
}
section.parallax-section.content-parallax-section {
    padding:150px 0;
}
```

original Image link: http://test.dvinsconceptzion.com/demo/includes/images/bg/2.jpg 
webpage link: http://test.dvinsconceptzion.com/demo/about.php#sec5

It could be also after upload the image header having some issue. but I am not sure coz this is the first i am having issues with image orientation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually connected to the image EXIF. There are some things you can do:

1. You could try removing it from the image (Windows):

   - Right-click anywhere within the selected fields and choose “Properties.”
   - Click the “Details” tab.
   - At the bottom of the “Details” tab, you’ll see a link titled “Remove Properties and Personal Information.” Click this link.
   - Windows will ask whether you want to make a copy of the photo with this information removed, or if you want to remove the information from the original. Choose the option you prefer and click “OK.”

Source: https://us.norton.com/internetsecurity-how-to-how-to-remove-gps-and-other-metadata-locations-from-photos.html

2. You can use a tool to rotate it and save again in the same orientation (like Photoshop or even Windows image viewer);
3. Or you can modify your uploader to add an `exif_read_data()` (if you're using PHP) to check the orientation and rotate it whenever needed. This answer could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34287543

Comment: I guess ```exif_read_data()``` this would be more handy for me.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Make    Apple
Model   iPhone 6 Plus
Orientation Rotate 90 CW
XResolution 72
YResolution 72
ResolutionUnit  inches
Software    10.3.2
ModifyDate  2017:07:20 12:12:58
YCbCrPositioning    Centered
ExposureTime    1/33
FNumber 2.2
ExposureProgram Program AE
```

Rotation recorded in EXIF data

I attach the [link](https://www.uploadimage.ca/image/EUgJ) with the changed data

```
Orientation Horizontal (normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use

```css
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

to rotate the image

Comment: but the issue is its not universal. what I am trying to say is this will my last option to create a class to rotate all those are this type. but if I could find the reason that'll be very usefulll