# Problem with image orientation after upload

Tags: php, file-upload, orientation

I have php code for uploading, resize and watemark photos. Everything works perfectly except when the photo is uploaded from some mobile devices, and then there is a problem with the wrong orientation of the photo (the photo is rotated by 90°)
I found a few solutions ([How to check/fix image rotation before upload image using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287437/how-to-check-fix-image-rotation-before-upload-image-using-php)) but I can't implement it in my code because I don't know enough php.
I believe I need to do the orientation correction before setting the watermark. This is code without orientation correction:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name =$_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'][$key]; 

            // Remove encoding problem
            $file_name = Normalizer::normalize($file_name); 
            setlocale(LC_ALL,'bs_BA.UTF-8'); 


            // get file extension
            $fileType = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); 

            $temp = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $name = str_replace($temp, '', $file_name);


            // get filename without extension
            $fileNewName = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $watermarkImagePath = 'watermark.png'; 
            $folderPath = "upload/";
            $sourceProperties = getimagesize($file_tmp);
            $imageType = $sourceProperties[2];

            // Resize code
            switch ($imageType) {
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefrompng($file_tmp); 
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                imagepng($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. ".jpg");
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromgif($file_tmp); 
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                imagegif($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. ".jpg");
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_tmp); 
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                imagejpeg($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. ".jpg");
                break;
            default:
                echo "Invalid Image type.";
                exit;
                break;
            }   

                // watermark code
                $NewFile=$fileNewName.'.jpg';
                $targetFilePath = $folderPath . $NewFile; 
                $watermarkImg = imagecreatefrompng($watermarkImagePath); 

                if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/i', $NewFile)) {  
                $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFilePath);  
              } else if (preg_match('/[.](jpeg)$/i', $NewFile)) {  
                $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFilePath);  
              } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/i', $NewFile)) {  
                $im = imagecreatefrompng($targetFilePath);  
              }  else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/i', $NewFile)) {  
                $im = imagecreatefromgif($targetFilePath);  
              }  

                $marge_right = 1; 
                $marge_bottom = 1; 

                $sx = imagesx($watermarkImg); 
                $sy = imagesy($watermarkImg); 

                imagecopy($im, $watermarkImg, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($watermarkImg), imagesy($watermarkImg)); 


                imagejpeg($im, $targetFilePath,70); 
                imagedestroy($im); 


    }
     echo ' Successful upload';
}
function imageResize($imageResourceId,$width,$height) {
if($width > $height){
    $targetWidth=1000;
    $targetHeight=($height/$width)*$targetWidth;
} else {
    $targetHeight=1000;
$targetWidth=($width/$height)*$targetHeight;}
    $targetLayer=imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth,$targetHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($targetLayer,$imageResourceId,0,0,0,0,$targetWidth,$targetHeight, $width,$height);
    return $targetLayer;
}

?>
<div class="sender">
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image[]" multiple/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form></div>
```

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but this is not really a problem. It's more a question of you asking us to write the code for you. That's not what Stack Overflow is for. Your problem basically is: I don't know enough PHP, and the solution to that seems clear to me: Learn it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I understand that this is simple for you and everything is clear. Unfortunately I have been trying for several hours to implement the code from the link I provided and I have no success. Just asking for help. Thanks for the advice, you were very helpful

Comment: Also, trying to solve problems like these is best way to learn. Yes, it can take hours, but next time you'll know what to do. Your assumption, that you need to rotate the image before watermarking it, is correct. One tip: Only write the image to disk after all the processing is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that works for me now. The image orientation correction code is in lines 50-70. There may be a better solution, but this is the only thing I have managed to do, to work properly:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name =$_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'][$key];      

            // Remove encoding problem
            $file_name = Normalizer::normalize($file_name); 
            setlocale(LC_ALL,'bs_BA.UTF-8');        

            // get file extension
            $fileType = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); 

            $temp = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $name = str_replace($temp, '', $file_name);

            // get filename without extension
            $fileNewName = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $watermarkImagePath = 'watermark.png'; 
            $folderPath = "a/";
            $sourceProperties = getimagesize($file_tmp);
            $imageType = $sourceProperties[2];

            // Resize code
            switch ($imageType) {
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefrompng($file_tmp); 
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                imagepng($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. ".jpg");
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromgif($file_tmp); 
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                imagegif($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. ".jpg");
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $imageResourceId = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_tmp); 
                $targetLayer = imageResize($imageResourceId,$sourceProperties[0],$sourceProperties[1]);
                imagejpeg($targetLayer,$folderPath. $fileNewName. ".jpg");

                break;
            default:
                echo "Invalid Image type.";
                exit;
                break;
            }               

        // Image Orientation correction                         

        $targetFilePath = $folderPath . $file_name;                 
        $exif = exif_read_data($file_tmp);
        if ($exif['Orientation']==3 OR $exif['Orientation']==6 OR $exif['Orientation']==8) {
            $imageResource = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFilePath); 
            switch ($exif['Orientation']) { 
            case 3:
            $image = imagerotate($imageResource, 180, 0);
            break;
            case 6:
            $image = imagerotate($imageResource, -90, 0);
            break;
            case 8:
            $image = imagerotate($imageResource, 90, 0);
            break;
        } 
        imagejpeg($image, $targetFilePath);
        imagedestroy($imageResource);
        imagedestroy($image);
        }

        // watermark code

                $watermarkImg = imagecreatefrompng($watermarkImagePath); 

                if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/i', $file_name)) {  
                $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFilePath);  
              } else if (preg_match('/[.](jpeg)$/i', $file_name)) {  
                $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFilePath);  
              } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/i', $file_name)) {  
                $im = imagecreatefrompng($targetFilePath);  
              }  else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/i', $file_name)) {  
                $im = imagecreatefromgif($targetFilePath);  
              }  

                $marge_right = 1; 
                $marge_bottom = 1; 

                $sx = imagesx($watermarkImg); 
                $sy = imagesy($watermarkImg); 

                imagecopy($im, $watermarkImg, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($watermarkImg), imagesy($watermarkImg)); 


                imagejpeg($im, $targetFilePath,70); 
                imagedestroy($im);     

    }
     echo ' Successful upload';
}
function imageResize($imageResourceId,$width,$height) {
if($width > $height){
    $targetWidth=1000;
    $targetHeight=($height/$width)*$targetWidth;
} else {
    $targetHeight=1000;
$targetWidth=($width/$height)*$targetHeight;}
    $targetLayer=imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth,$targetHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($targetLayer,$imageResourceId,0,0,0,0,$targetWidth,$targetHeight, $width,$height);
    return $targetLayer;
}

?>
<div class="sender">
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image[]" multiple/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is due to exchangeable information in photos.
mostly photos captured from iphone or DSLR have exif data.

```
   <?php
    $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES['image_upload']['tmp_name']));
    $exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['image_upload']['tmp_name']);
    if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    switch($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 8:
            $image = imagerotate($image,90,0);
            break;
        case 3:
            $image = imagerotate($image,180,0);
            break;
        case 6:
            $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
            break;
    }
}
// $image now contains a resource with the image oriented correctly
?>
```

above is code to fix rotation

refer this for more info
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php